# User enters any number but only store number that are divisible by 3 and display back

Tags: javascript, arrays

Prepare script to store data into an array. The user can enter any number, but ONLY store value that is divisible by number three. Then, display back the data (stored in Array) on HTML page.

I need to do this using JavaScript code. How do store value the value and display? Thank you.

Comment: we need a snippet of code that you have tried in order to give you hints and direct answers (in some cases).

Comment: `Array.prototype.filter` and modulus operator are your friends here

Comment: For how much time you want to store the entered values? Only valid for current session?

Comment: *The user can enter any number, but ONLY store value that is divisible by number three* --> Using prompt? or how?

Comment: @P.hunter
var arr = [];                             

for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {              
  arr.push(prompt('Enter a number ')); 
}

alert(' ' + arr.join(''));
 yes only for current session

Comment: Have posted an answer as per my understanding, Check it and let me know for further changes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you required?

```js
var numbers = []; // Array to store the valid numbers

function openPromt() {
 var num = prompt("Please enter a number", "0");
 storeIfNumValid(num);
}

openPromt();

// funtion that will call after each value from `prompt`
function storeIfNumValid(num) {
 if (num != null && num % 3 === 0) {
  numbers.push(num);
  openPromt();
 } else {
  console.log(numbers);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = numbers;
 }
}
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```